# CircularReveal animation doesn't work on first attempt

Tags: android, animation, android-5.0-lollipop

In android 5.0 i am trying to work with circular reveal animation

Problem

When i click on button to start reveal animation, on first click animation doesn't start

Second Click onwards it works normally

My Code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Animator a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final View cardType = findViewById(R.id.cardtype);
    cardType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        a = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(cardType,
                cardType.getWidth(),
                cardType.getHeight(),
                0,
                cardType.getHeight() * 2)
                .setDuration(2500);
        a.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                cardType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        a.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                cardType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.icon_first_activity).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a.start();
            }
        });
    }
}}
```

Comment: Hey, have you managed to fix this? I'm having the exact same problem and can't find a solution.

Comment: @NikolaK. yes i solved it 
The solution is don't use values directly like in my code `cardType.getWidth()` should not be passed directly, it takes time to load. Best way is to get values from other activity or something, so that animation and value get some time in between to initialise

Comment: There's logic in what you're saying. I tried passing already calculated variables as parameters of the method, and the issue is still there :( I even tried writing raw values instead of variables, and that didn't fix it either.

Comment: @NikolaK. but that worked for me

Comment: My solution was to add 1000ms `CountDownTimer` (can be shorther). Still no idea what's the problem, but it works fine now, and the delayed effect is actually better for me.

Comment: As @G.Blake Meike suggested, I made the View from GONE to INVISIBLE. It started working. Its because When GONE is measured for first time, the  width and height of the view is 0.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I haven't tried your code, but I think you have a small ordering problem.  I think you just need to set the `cardType` visible *before* you start the animation.

**Edited to add:**

... and you should be setting your button View.INVISIBLE, not View.GONE.

Here:  [This code works](https://github.com/bmeike/Yamba5Studio/blob/lolly2/app/src/main/java/com/twitter/university/android/yamba/TweetFragment.java).

**Edited once more to add:**

Yes.  Your problem is that you set the view GONE initially.  That means it has 0 size.  Then you use `cardType.getHeight` and `cardType.getWidth` as reveal coordinates.  They are 0.  You are going to want to set the view INVISIBLE, initially, and then use width/2 and height/2 as the center of the reveal.

Comment: So, there may be other problems as well, but you definitely need to do at least that.

Comment: `onAnimationStart` do same thing

Comment: That was exactly my problem. My View was set to `GONE`, and the animation was not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Basically what others answers say, it's correct, but the problem is if you want visibility GONE (because your layout requires it GONE!) you have to set visibility INVISIBLE in the xml with height 0dp (and/or width 0dp as well) and programmatically set the correct LayoutParams even inside the click event it will work. For example my code:

```
    ...
    expandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //To not have empty scroll, the container is INVISIBLE with 0dp height.
            //Otherwise the Reveal effect will not work at the first click.
            //Here I set the parameters programmatically.
            viewContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            if (viewContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                expandButton.animate().rotation(0f).setDuration(duration).start();
                Utils.unReveal(viewContainer, 0, 0);
            } else {
                expandButton.animate().rotation(180f).setDuration(duration).start();
                Utils.reveal(viewContainer, viewContainer.getWidth(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
    ...

@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void reveal(final View view, int cx, int cy) {
    if (!hasLollipop()) {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return;
    }

    //Get the final radius for the clipping circle
    int finalRadius = Math.max(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());

    //Create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator animator =
            ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

    //Make the view VISIBLE and start the animation
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    animator.start();
}

@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void unReveal(final View view, int cx, int cy) {
    if (!hasLollipop()) {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }

    //Get the initial radius for the clipping circle
    int initialRadius = view.getWidth();

    //Create the animation (the final radius is zero)
    Animator animator =
        ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0);

    //Make the view GONE when the animation is done
    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    //Start the animation
    animator.start();
}
```

If you set only GONE in the xml, the first time will never work because height/width/x/y/etc.. are 0. Also, if you just set INVISIBLE before the call to the animation it will *not* work as well, but if you start with visibility INVISIBLE it will initialize the layout params.

Answer (score 0):

what i did is, Like i have two view with same height,As we now visibility gone returns 0 {height and width} than i am giving visible view height every time and its work for me.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is don't get values directly into code
Either put the animation code on click and the values outside onclick
or get the values from other activity
By values i mean `cardType.getWidth()` and `cardType.getHeight()`

Comment: Can you share a gist of the code that worked, because I'm having a similar problem as you are and I can't figure it out.

Comment: @McAdam331 where are you tying to load it, on start of activity or on click?

Comment: I put the code in onwindowfocuschanged. I don't start the animation until a button is clicked.

Comment: @McAdam331 initialise Animator outside onwindowfocuschanged and onclick

Comment: Where did you initialize yours? I can't do it inside `onCreate()` because I won't be able to call `getLeft()` and `getRight()` on the view yet.